# Firestore - Write Array of Custom Objects

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Cloud Firestore collection for user vehicles. Each document is tied to the user's UID from authentication. I have managed to write out a custom Vehicle POJO to the collection, but I can only write one vehicle at a time.

How can I handle so that each time the user adds another vehicle, it adds it to the document as an array? So you'd have `vehicle[0]`, `vehicle[1]` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I handle so that each time the user adds another vehicle, it adds it to the document as an array?

You can achieve this by simply calling `update()` method like in the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference vehicleIdRef = rootRef.collection("vehicles").document("vehicleId");
Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle("VehicleName");
vehicleIdRef.update("vehicleArray", FieldValue.arrayUnion(vehicle));
```

Which will atomically add a new "Vehicle" object to the "vehicleArray" array field. More informations [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

Please also note, that this technique will work only if you don't have a `Date` property in your class, otherwise you'll get an error like this:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. FieldValue.serverTimestamp() can only be used with set() and update()

Comment: Hey Alex! Sorry, been on a min-vacation from code :) I was able to get that working. Follow up (if you don't mind) - how can I get them back out? I am currently have a vehicle Document that is the user UUID and nested Vehicle objects under them. But when I try to retrieve, I end up getting a blank object. I am also writing out the user's UUID to the Vehicle object so I can query based on fields that contain that UUID.

Comment: To provide a little more info, I am able to get the nested values out by converting to a Map and calling getData on the DocumentSnapshot. Then looping over the Map entry set. I have typically used Firestore's methods to convert the result back over to my custom object (e.g. documentSnapshot.toObject(POJO.class), but since I am getting the nested values as a Map, will I need to use something like Jackson or GSON?

Comment: Good to hear that it worked :) "how can I get them back out?" I cannot say much without seeing the code. So I recommend you to post another fresh question, so me and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Done! Thanks for helping a newbie out :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54545018/firestore-retrieve-nested-object-and-convert-to-pojo